# Certain sounds not working when creating a boxing timer in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, audio, timer

I'm trying to make a boxing stopwatch using Visual Studio and Visual Basic (so 3 minute clock, 10 second sprint and 30 second rest), and when the timer transitions into the next round/time e.g. 3 mins ends and rest break starts, a boxing bell sound should play. However, for some non apparent reason it just doesn't play during two times that it should. The only sound that plays is on the lines

`If CurrentTime < 5 Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)`

I have tried to replicate it in the two other instances of the sound play event but it still doesn't play. I'm not sure why. Let me know if you need me to explain what some code does, and I'm sorry there's so much here but I think it's needed to show the issue.

I have tried replicating the working line of code with the others but it doesn't work.

`If CurrentTime < 5 Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)`

`Public Class Form1
    Dim CurrentTime As Integer
    Dim Inactive, IsPaused As Boolean`

```
Private Sub btnQuit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuit.Click
    End
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    tmrInactive.Enabled = True

    btnQuit.Visible = True
    btnReset.Visible = True
    btnStart.Visible = True
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    If IsPaused = True Then
        If tmrRest.Enabled = False Then
            tmrStart.Enabled = True
            btnStart.Text = "Pause"
        End If
        If tmrStart.Enabled = False Then
            tmrRest.Enabled = True
        End If
        IsPaused = False

    ElseIf IsPaused = False Then
        btnStart.Text = "Resume"
        If tmrRest.Enabled = True Then
            tmrRest.Enabled = False

        End If
        tmrStart.Enabled = False
        IsPaused = True

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub tmrStart_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrStart.Tick
    CurrentTime = CurrentTime - 1
    lblSeconds.Text = CStr(CurrentTime Mod 60)
    lblMinutes.Text = CStr(CurrentTime \ 60)

    If CurrentTime > 10 Then
        lblMinutes.ForeColor = Color.Green
        lblSeconds.ForeColor = Color.Green
        lblColon.BackColor = Color.Green
        lblColon2.BackColor = Color.Green
    ElseIf CurrentTime <= 10 And CurrentTime > 0 Then
        lblMinutes.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
        lblSeconds.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
        lblColon.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        lblColon2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        If CurrentTime < 14 Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)

        End If

    ElseIf CurrentTime = 14 Then

    ElseIf CurrentTime = 0 Then
        lblMinutes.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblSeconds.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblColon.BackColor = Color.Red
        lblColon2.BackColor = Color.Red
        tmrStart.Enabled = False
        tmrRest.Enabled = True
        lblSeconds.Text = 30
        CurrentTime = 30

    ElseIf CurrentTime = 10 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)



    End If

End Sub

Private Sub lblSeconds_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblSeconds.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    IsPaused = True
    btnStart.Text = "Start"
    CurrentTime = 180
End Sub

Private Sub tmrRest_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrRest.Tick
    CurrentTime = CurrentTime - 1
    lblSeconds.Text = CStr(CurrentTime Mod 60)
    lblMinutes.Text = CStr(CurrentTime \ 60)
    If CurrentTime < 5 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        CurrentTime = 180
        tmrRest.Enabled = False
        tmrStart.Enabled = True

    End If
    If CurrentTime > 29 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    btnStart.Text = "Start"
    CurrentTime = 180
    lblMinutes.Text = "3"
    lblSeconds.Text = "00"
End Sub

Private Sub tmrInactive_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrInactive.Tick
    btnQuit.Visible = False
    btnReset.Visible = False
    btnStart.Visible = False
    tmrInactive.Enabled = False
```

It should play the sounds on the lines
`If CurrentTime > 29 Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        End If`

AND

`ElseIf CurrentTime = 10 Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        End If`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You should not be measuring time by counting.  You should be measuring time by measuring time.  The Framework actually includes a `Stopwatch` class.  You should use it.  Have your `Timer` `Tick` every 100 milliseconds or even less and then see how much time has elapsed based on a `Stopwatch` instance.  You can start, stop, pause and reset, just like a physical stopwatch.

Comment: Wire these sounds up to a few new buttons in the UI and click them. Do you hear the sounds okay? If yes then the code in the timer is perhaps faulty. If no then the sound file is to blame, or the code logic not firing properly?

Answer (score 0):

There are some strange combinations of checks on the CurrentTime value in that code. Inside a check for `<=10` and `>0`, you also check to see if its `<14`, which of course it always will be. You also have a check for `=10`, as well as the `<=10 and >0` mentioned above.

This section of code in the tick handler for tmr_rest

```
    If CurrentTime > 29 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)
    End If
```

won't execute, surely? When you enable tmrrest inside tmr_start, you set `currentTime=30`, then at the very start of tmrrest-tick handler, you decrease it by one, so by the time it hits that code, it'll never be `>29`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what Resources tab looks like.
[image]

Notice that the name is `Stop`.
Here is the code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources._Stop, AudioPlayMode.Background)
End Sub
```

Notice that the name of the Resource is `_Stop`.

Try placing an underscore in front of SprintBell

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources._SprintBell, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

I believe that `AudioPlayMode.Background` is the default and not necessary.